# Text under icons in PCManFM and Desktop are gone

Tags: linux, debian, icons, themes, label

I was messing about with cursor themes, and all of a sudden, my text goes. it happened on my desktop, but I thought it didn't matter cause I could still pcmanfm, right? Well yeah, but not for long. By the way, this is ROOT that is f'd up! not just another user, root! I can only use root because I can't sign into another user, (on GUI I mean), so I've been using it for a while. If anyone can also fix the black screen with cursor for 1 second after sign in, that would help.

- Desktop with empty text

A highlighted icon text shows a small blue box

[[Click to see the image (will post direct when reputation goes up)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EYXQa.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EYXQa.jpg)

- The more recent one

[[Click to see the image (will post direct when reputation goes up)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2FMdY.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2FMdY.png)

EDIT: So after a restart, the PCManFM labels are back, but not the desktop ones.
EDIT 2: Solved: My font size was 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The font size is 0. Set it to a larger number than 0.